# How to specify custom Java toolchain URL to download in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, toolchain, adoptopenjdk, java-21

Configuration

```
toolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
}
```

fails with the following message:

```
  > Unable to download toolchain matching these requirements: {languageVersion=21, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}
     > Unable to download toolchain. This might indicate that the combination (version, architecture, release/early access, ...) for the requested JDK is not available.
        > Could not read 'https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/21/ga/windows/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk' as it does not exist.
```

How can I specify to download JDK from **early access** release type:
https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/21/ea/windows/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk

Comment: `Gradle only downloads JDK versions for GA releases. There is no support for downloading early access versions.` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html